# New Connection Error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, connection, selenium-ide

I've imported Selenium IDE program to python file and ran it in terminal but I get this error code. It works in Selenium IDE.

I'm trying to connect to an external website and click some buttons. After which, the program would send me an email to say it is done